# How does the command "plot(qnorm)" work in R?

Tags: r, statistics

When i run the command `plot(qnorm)` , it produce the following graph :
[image]

But i am not understanding how does the command work for producing the graph ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`qnorm` is a function, so it is insightful to look for a function that follows the S3 convention of `plot.function`. If you read the help, you'll see that this function:

> Draws a curve corresponding to a function over the interval
>        '[from, to]'. 'curve' can plot also an expression in the variable
>        'xname', default 'x'.

Since you are not specifying the range, further on down the help documentation, it states:

> What happens when neither 'from'/'to' nor 'xlim' specifies both
>        x-limits is a complex story.  For 'plot()' and for
>        'curve(add = FALSE)' the ***defaults are (0, 1)***.  For 'curve(add =
>        NA)' and 'curve(add = TRUE)' the defaults are taken from the
>        x-limits used for the previous plot.  (This differs from versions
>        of R prior to 2.14.0.)

(highlight added for emphasis).

So, your call to `plot(qnorm)` is analogous to `curve(qnorm, from = 0, to = 1)` per `plot.function`.

Comment: So x are taking values from 0 to 1. and for each point in 0<=x<=1, say x=.6, qnorm is analogous to qnorm(.6)

Comment: Yes. (It is convenient -- or a well-chosen default, more likely -- that `qnorm` is undefined outside of [0,1].)